# Environment properties files in scala project

Tags: scala, configuration, environment

Just starting to learn scala for a new project. Have got to the point where I would like to define different properties files for the different environments the app is going to run on, ideally in a similar way to Rails - very lightweight, just one different properties file per environment that is loaded based on its name. I don't really care if it's a java properties file, YML or scala code.

In the spirit of not reinventing the wheel I've been looking to see if there is some accepted standard Scala way of doing this but I can't find one, I've found a few similar but not identical questions here where people suggest using system properties in the startup script but this feels like it would end up being a nightmare.

I could obviously implement it if needs be but feels like the sort of thing that should already exist. So - does it?

I'm using sbt if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of [Configgy](https://github.com/robey/configgy). Also, Akka/Play 2.0 will be using [Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config), which looks nice too. See [blog](http://blog.ometer.com/2011/12/09/configuring-the-typesafe-stack/) about the latter.

Basically, Configgy has been used for a while now, but has been deprecated, while Config will be all-new. However, having Config as the default [Typesafe Stack](http://typesafe.com/stack) configuration tool will probably make it the preferred tool for that pretty fast.

Comment: I had a look at Configgy which appears to have been replaced by Ostrich which seems very heavy-weight for what I want and also centred around servers. Will have a look at Config now though, thanks.

Comment: Typesafe Config is the best Config lib I've used so far, and we were using Configgy previously.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a Configgy replacement called [Configrity](https://github.com/paradigmatic/Configrity). It can use different input formats (like YAML), it's immutable, supports functional patterns and uses type class to convert automatically the values to the desired type.

Comment: You should add it to the scala tools&libraries wiki.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: someone did it. It was filled in the miscellaneous section.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a "config" section. There should be, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have written BeeConfig, a replacement for java.util.Properties except that it is a Scala API and uses UTF-encoded configuration files. It supports string interpolation, chaining and a bunch of other features. But its main objective is simplicity.

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/rickb777/beeconfig/overview) | [Blog post](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/blog/bee-config-replaces-properties-in-scala)

Rick